# What does dollar($) represent in a Spring bean property?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a bean that looks something like this:

```xml
<bean id="envUtil" class="com.environment.util.MainClass">
    <property name="config1" value="${var1}"></property>
    <property name="config2" value="${var2}"></property>
</bean>
```

Now I understand the class `com.environment.util.MainClass` gets initiated when the application shoots up.

But how does its data members `config1` and `config2` get their value?

What does the expression `"${var1}"` mean?
And from where will this `var` be read?

I am new to Spring so please excuse me if the question is trivial.

Comment: It represents a placeholder variable to be filled-in. See: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#usage

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl From where will var1 be read ?

Comment: Did you see the link above? It is coming from a properties file. This file can be declared in the XML or injected in via command line arguments. Look up examples of `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />`.

Comment: It is basically SPeL https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It can come from anywhere that Spring can resolve it, which includes Spring Boot environment configuration and cloud resolvers like Vault or AWS Parameter Store.